# what is the inverse function of Sinc

Tags: math, numerical-methods

I've searching the whole day to calculate the inverse function of `sinc(x)`  between `-pi  and pi` , but couldn't find anything:

[image]

Does anybody know a way to get the angle value from the a given `sinc` value ?  If it make easier I'm only interested in the area between `-pi and pi` 
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/542353/does-sinc-function-have-any-special-inverse-function-defined

Comment: @duffymo I've read that already, at Mark what do yyou mean

Comment: Would you consider using numerical methods?

Comment: @andand oh yeah I would

Comment: @Engine It may behave poorly in places (in particular where the derivative of the function approaches 0), but you might be able to use Newton's Method to approximate zeros of y = sinc(x)-y0 where y0 = sinc(x0) and you're looking for an x0 which satisfies the equation.  I haven't tried it and I don't know how well it will converge for some of the initial iterations.  But it may be worth a try to see if it works.

Comment: @andand the approximation sould only work between -pi and pi meaning the first zeros

Comment: I'll be greatfull for any hint

Comment: @Engine Couple of observations.  The first is there are two branches on the interval x in [-pi, pi] so you probably are better served looking on the range [0, pi] instead.  The other, is you're finding zeros of sinc(x)-y0 given some value of y0 on the interval [0, 1].  Zeros for sinc(x)-y0 where y0=0 is trivially pi.

Comment: if you could provide me with a formel,I get a better understand  it better

Comment: @Engine... detail for what I describe is in the answer below.

Answer (score 6):

In general, even if restricted to small intervals where *sinc* is [bijective](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection) (which I don't think is the case for your requirements), [it has no simple inverse](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/inverse-of-sinc.282941/).

Perhaps you could do one of the following:

1. You could calculate the inverse "online" using the minimization of of *abs(sinc(x) - y)* (see, e.g., [Numerical Recipes in C](https://www.google.co.il/search?q=numerical+methods+c+minimizing&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=rhdSVdWEAsizsQGM74H4BQ). Note that you're in luck as it's a smooth function, and so you can use the derivatives.
2. Create "offline" a lookup table for various values in the required range, and given an "online" query, interpolate between two pre-calculated results.

Comment: It would be easier to solve `0=sin(x)-x·y`. It has a neater looking derivative.

Comment: @LutzL That's a very smart observation.

Comment: @Ami thanks for your help , well in my case I need only the first part ( the Prabola tell the X axis : mean tell  -PI and+ PI

Answer (score 1):

[Newton's Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) for finding zeros may be serve as a means to approximate inverses for the [sinc function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SincFunction.html).  If we let `f(x) = sin(x)/x`, then `f'(x) = cos(x)/x-sin(x)/x^2`  Using Newton's method, we can approximate a zero for `f` by

```
 x(n+1) = x(n) - f(x(n)) / f'(x(n))
```

Depending where we start and as long as we don't come across values where `f'(x(n)) = 0` we should find a solution.

If we restrict `f` to a single branch where `x∈(0,π]` then `f(x)∈[0,1)` is bijective and Newton's Method may be useful to finding `x0∈(0,π]` for a given `y0∈[0,1)` such that `y0=f(x0)`.  We can do this by finding where `g(x0)=f(x0)-y0=0`.  In this case `g'(x) = f'(x)` since the derivative of `y0` is 0. and so we're left with iterating:

```
 x(n+1) = x(n) - [f(x(n)) - y0] / f'(x(n))
```

The trick then is to choose a suitable `x(0)` to start the process.  There are likely a number of possible choices, but `x(0)=π` is probably adequate.

One caveat to this is you will need to guard against the possibility of `f'(x(n))=0`.  This condition should be checked and if it is encountered,  a different `x(0)` should be chosen and the process started again.

Comment: Very good initial values can be obtained from the Taylor approximation `y=sinc(x)=1-t/3!+t²/5!-t²/7!+…` where `t:=x²`. Analytical solutions are available up to quartic order.